# stored procedure generating msg 512 Subquery returned more than 1 value

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

In Sql Server 2019 I am getting

> msg 512 Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

in several places the first is in this section.

```sql
IF (SELECT Job FROM [PRODUCTION].[dbo].[Job] WHERE Part_Number = @PN) is null
    SELECT @Job='NOTHING'
ELSE
    SELECT @Job = (SELECT Job FROM [PRODUCTION].[dbo].[Job] WHERE Status_Date = (SELECT 
       Max(Status_Date) FROM [PRODUCTION].[dbo].[Job] WHERE Part_Number = @PN  AND Status = 
      'Closed'))
```

I can run the query by itself and always get only one result. I have tried the query using `TOP 1` and I still get msg 512.

Comment: `SELECT Max(Status_Date) ...` always gets only one result. `SELECT Job FROM [PRODUCTION].[dbo].[Job] WHERE Status_Date = (...)`, not necessarily. It is also a subquery in your design.

Comment: I bet adding `top(1)` to `if (select job` will resolve it.

Comment: If you search the internet for that message you will find many discussions about why this error occurs and how to fix (or even avoid) it. But it seems you have a common "first in group" query and a very different approach would be more appropriate.

Comment: I have tried using TOP 1 and still get the error.  Max(Status_Date) does only return one value

Comment: The error will be from your first `if`, not the `else`; it will not matter if the `select` in the else returns many rows, assigning to `@job` is perfectly legal, however `if(many rows) is null` is a no-go.

Answer (score 1):

You have two of the same logic flaws in your code. You know the IF statement is a problem as it has already been noted. So it is avoided by replacing:

```
IF (SELECT Job FROM [PRODUCTION].[dbo].[Job] WHERE Part_Number = @PN) is null
    SELECT @Job='NOTHING'
```

with

```
if not exists (select * from dbo.Job where Part_Number = @PN) 
   set @Job = 'NOTHING';
```

Note the better practices. Removed the database name since the connection should determine that. Remove the square brackets because they are not needed. Use SET to assign scalar values not SELECT. Statement terminators. Etc.

The additional error is in the select statement use to retrieve the job value. Removing the extra fluff for assignment, you have:

```
SELECT Job FROM [PRODUCTION].[dbo].[Job] 
 WHERE Status_Date = 
   (SELECT Max(Status_Date) 
      FROM [PRODUCTION].[dbo].[Job] 
     WHERE Part_Number = @PN  AND Status = 'Closed'
    )
```

Here the subquery will indeed select a single row for your desired part number and status. However, you only select a date and there might (and obviously are) many rows that have that particular date in column Status_Date. You did not limit that outer query to the appropriate part_number - which may or may not solve your issue (because I don't know your schema).

So rather than this error-prone approach, I suggest you search on the term I used in the comments and use the row_number approach to access the "first row" (which is really the last row in descending order).

For completeness, you could change your assignment to:

```
set @Job = (top 1 Job from dbo.Job 
      where Part_Number = @PN and Status = 'Closed' order by Status_Date desc);
```

That might also "avoid" the problem but I cannot say without knowledge of your schema. Presumably many jobs can have the same Part_Number so I think there is something missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following inverted logic using `exists`

```
if exists (select * from dbo.job where part_number = @PN)
  select @job= (....)
else
  select @Job='NOTHING'
```